# How to install protractor and start it?

Tags: protractor

I followed instructions in the document on how to install protractor and selenium and I am unable to start.

```
install -g protractor

webdriver-manager update
```

After that I tried

`webdriver-manager start` and I got an error

```
events.jst:72
throw er; // Unhandeled 'error event
Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_projcess.js:980:11)
at Process.ChildProcess.handle.onexeit (childprocess.js:771:34)
```

If I do `webdriver-manager status` I get this

```
selenium standalone is up to date
chromedriver is up to date
IEDriver is not present
```

What is going on?

Comment: Hmm... did you restart your computer?
BTW, I use [grunt-protractor-runner](https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner) and don't need to start webdriver manually.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are running on the mac platform.

Installing it globally as you are doing, installs it to the system's node_module folder.  You should try and install it locally for the project as its a project dependency.

so run:
**npm install protractor**

Answer (score 3):

Kind of old, but what solved it for me was to install java:

In an Ubuntu system:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`

In Fedora:

`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk`

Keep hacking!

Answer (score 0):

First install globally `npm i -g protractor`

Secondly install locally `npm i protractor`